# What component is the infinite volume knob?

Tags: components, volume

I am looking for the name of potentiometer like component which built in keyboards like Logitech G910, it sending just a plus and minus data I assume. Thanks

Comment: It's probably just a rotary switch or encoder (unlikely). You can easily figure this out by opening it up and looking at it.

Comment: I assumed it to be a encoder which outputs gray code.

Comment: That's basically the same as scroll wheel on mouse.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_encoder#Quadrature_outputs

Answer (score 5):

You are describing a rotary encoder.

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical rotary encoder.*

These consist of two switching contacts (mechanical or optical) which give out a train of pulses offset by 90°.

[image]

*Figure 2. The output waveform and the resultant count when rotating clockwise and anti-clockwise.*

The offset allows determination of rotation direction. If, for example, we check the status of B every time A goes positive we can say:

- If B is '0' then increment the count by 1.
- If B is '1' then decrement the count by 1.

See [Rotary encoder to 2 buttons](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/231811/73158) for more and a sample circuit.